# jQuery File Upload – UI version submit multiple files with single post request

Tags: jquery-file-upload

Even if you set singleFileUploads to false, if you do multiple individual selections, still sends with individual requests as below.

```
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        singleFileUploads: false
    });
```

Way forward?

Comment: set the fileupload so a single file input so you can only load one upload item in your form.

Comment: I would like to submit multiple files with one request

Comment: I reckon  you'd have all the file inputs in one form, hence one request. Hard to tell, can you post your code here please?